# Can a plain text email contain XSS injection?

Tags: email, xss

I need to send a plain text email with user-specified input.

For example, if a user is an attacker a plain text email can contain

```
<script>alert(1)</script>
```

It looks like mail clients should treat it just as plain text and it shouldn't pose any threat to end recipients. Am I supposed to sanitize user input by removing all unwanted HTML tags in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No, plain-text email cannot contain a [cross-site scripting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) (XSS) attack.**
XSS requires scripting, which even HTML email bodies***** do not permit.

<sup>(*****HTML *attachments* opened in web browsers can trigger XSS attacks, just as macros can run when you open them in Office.)</sup>

A plain-text email containing HTML data, including script tags like `<script>` or attributes like `<a onmouseover="…">`, will simply render them literally (unless there are some horrible bugs in the email client).

No sanitizing should be needed.

---

Aside: On the threat detection front, I should note that a surprising number of legitimate and marketing emails do actually include scripting in their HTML email bodies (which of course is never evaluated by email or webmail clients), so such basic cues are not even good signals of attacks.

Comment: *" requires scripting. which even HTML email bodies do not permit"* - this might be true for *inline* HTML but is not true for HTML as *attachment*, which is also part of the email body. An attached HTML file with script is actually a common attack vector. It will result in executing the HTML with the locally installed browser and will thus also execute Javascript. Still, the answer is right in that script code in plain text parts is not a problem.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich – Correct, that's why I said "email _bodies_" to differentiate from email _attachments_, which need to be opened in web browsers just as macro attacks need to be opened in their respective applications. I'll update the answer to be more explicit there.

Comment: Sorry for being annoyingly fussy, but when looking the the standards the [body](https://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc5322.html#body) is actually the part after the mail header, which then gets interpreted using [MIME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME) as a structure with MIME parts which can be inline or attached (or external), have different MIME types (like text/plain and text/html) etc. But again, I'm probably being annoyingly fussy here :) +1 for your answer.

Comment: Yes. Technically, the whole MIME payload is the RFC 5322 "body" but mail clients use the MIME "disposition" to determine what should be rendered as the body versus resources for the body versus attachments. Mail clients (including web mail) shouldn't evaluate scripts in any HTML they render, especially the body, though they will let you open HTML attachments in a web browser. There are interesting tricks that can be done with CSS, but I don't know of any exploits there. Just web beacons and impressive animations.